# IN condition with parameters using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, sqlalchemy, sql-server-2005

I'm need some help for making a query with SQLalchemy and SQL server using a simple web form.

Form fields are **datefrom**, **dateto**, and **name** so any user can filter the query base on their preferences.

**datefrom**, **dateto** are selected from a datepicker and they can be left blank to wider the query.

**name** is a multiselect item list: you can select one, two or none. If none is selected I want to query all the **names** in the database (more than 20).

SQL query file is external and load in the script.

**python script:**

```
params = {'date_from': date_from,
              'date_to': date_to,
              'names': names
         }

    with engine.connect() as con:
        with open(query_file, 'r') as query:
            sql = sqlalchemy.text(query.read())
            for key in params.keys():
                if type(params[key]) == list:
                    sql = sql.bindparams(bindparam(key, expanding=True))
            rs = con.execute(sql, params)
            results = pd.DataFrame(rs.fetchall(), columns=query_columns)
```

**sql script:**

```
 WHERE (
    (date >= :datefrom OR :datefrom IS NULL)
    AND
    (date <= :dateto OR :dateto IS NULL)
    )
    AND (user IN :name OR :name IS NULL)
```

The problem is with the IN condition.
We have 3 cases.

CASE 1.
:name = ['Mark']

CASE 2.
:name = None (SQLalchemy change this to NULL)

CASE 3.
:name = ['Mark','John']

The problem with this solution is with the **3rd case** as SQLalchemy bind the query to ***(?,?) IS NULL*** which generates an error.

- I tried to solve this issue somehow in the SQL query without success.
  Using coalesce, CAST. I also use a flag and tried to use the order of
  precedence in the SQL statements to short something.
- Another try was to convert the list to a string and use that as
  parameter.
- The only that I didn't try yet is adding this WHERE clauses
  dynamically base of the user input and avoid checking things in the
  SQL query. Something like:

  sql += " AND user IN :name"

Thanks!

Comment: Remove the name is null condition and instead pass a blank string in your users array.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply mate! I tried that but no results are displayed if I remove the condition in the sql query. I want all the names if name field is left empty.

Comment: Add another parameters `NoUsers bit` and change your condition to `name in `Users or NoUsers = true`, and use logic in your code to set that parameter. Sorry that more T-SQL since I'm not familiar with Python, but you get the drift.

Comment: Well. finally Is working with a mix of your tips. I added another parameter as a flag and use an empy string as parameter instead of None